# Changing City in Shipping to Drop Down options

Tags: magento-1.9

I just want to change the city input field into a drop down list. I tried the Region Manager extensions to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated! The reason why I need this is because I am running a matrixtable that requires certain cities and if those are mispelled or left blank, the shipping rate will just be free.

I added this into the

> template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml

but then the shipping method fails to recognize the city selected:

```
<select id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('City')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="shipping:city" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);">
    <option value=" " disabled selected><?php echo $this->__('Select one...') ?></option>
    <option value="Woodbridge">Woodbridge</option>
    <option value="Maple">Maple</option>
</select>
```